# get single FetchedObject from FCR to write Label

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a problem with my FCR. I want to show my datas on Labels but FCR doesnt allow me.There is my codes..

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"faturaAdi == 'ADSL' "];
```

I have fetched only 1 data which fatura name is ADSL.. and I want to write this faturaAdi on my label but i couldn't do that.

```
NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc]init];

array = self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects;

_lblFaturaAdi.text = [self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects valueForKey:@"faturaAdi"];

NSLog(@"%@",[array valueForKey:@"faturaAdi"]);
```

NSLog shows Takip[967:60b] (
    ADSL
)

When i put the

`_lblFaturaAdi.text = [self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects valueForKey:@"faturaAdi"];`

app crash with this error ;

-[__NSArrayI length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa18c740

how can i solve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should change to:

```
NSArray *array = self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects;

if (array.count > 0) {
    self.lblFaturaAdi.text = [[array objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"faturaAdi"];

    NSLog(@"%@", _lblFaturaAdi.text);
} else {
    NSLog(@"no results found");
}
```

Because you don't need to initialise an array before replacing it and you need to index into the array before you can extract the value.

Comment: its working now Thank you. I have a problem too. How can I dont show or delete nil cell.text ? Because when I add some data except faturaAdi to my Fatura entity and when I list them. I see empty nil cell. Because my code is `cell.textlabel.text = fatura.faturaAdi` and I don't have faturaAdi text I added fatura entity something else. How can I delete or dont show this empty cell ? Again Thank you for your answer and sorry for my poor english.

Comment: If you have nothing to display then you should change the row count provided to the table so it doesn't try to display a cell.